# rsyslog filter by tag

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I would like to create a rsyslogd config file that filter the syslog for specific tag and outputs this tag to a specific file.

I create a rule file under `/etc/rsyslog.d`

```
# Log kernel generated UFW log messages to file
:syslogtag, isequal, "ABC" /var/log/ABC.log

# Uncomment the following to stop logging anything that matches the last rule.
# Doing this will stop logging kernel generated UFW log messages to the file
# normally containing kern.* messages (eg, /var/log/kern.log)
#& ~
```

The file is created, however the messages with ABC tag still go to the `syslog` file.
How do I do it correctly ?

Comment: Make sure that your **/etc/rsyslog.conf** contains > $IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/* If not add it, without it the service will not read the config added to the /etc/rsyslog.d/ folder. If that is present then try adding the rule directly to your **rsyslog.conf** file.

Comment: it already contains it. I think that I have an issue with the rule I declared, not the non-inclusion of it. (the file is created)

Comment: True, you are right about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rule file should look like:

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "ABC:" /var/log/ABC.log
```

The syslogtag contains a `:` and should be enclosed in `""`.

Also, the file name must be before `50-default.conf` in alphabetical order (for example `30-ABC.conf`).

Note that the file `/var/log/ABC.log` should be writable by the 'syslog' user.

Source: [how to filer rsyslog messages by tags](https://serverfault.com/q/514901/181186).